# Why my server js doesn't work on port 3000

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, port

I'm trying to create a server with express but I have a big problem, the server doesn't run.

This is the code of my simple file "server.js" and I follow the standard procedure to create it.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

And this is the message in the console when I run "node server.js"

```
C:\Users\Utente\Documents\Udemy_Corso_NodeJS\my-express-server\server.js:1
��c

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1049:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1084:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1174:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

Node.js v18.7.0
```

I don't understand which is the problem, obviously, also in the browser it doesn't work.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Looks like some kind of character encoding issue. You have some rogue bytes at the start of the file.

Comment: It looks like your file is using a text encoding with a byte-order-mark or similar at the beginning. Open the file in your editor and save it, taking care to change the encoding to UTF-8 without BOM. (You could use some other encodings, but UTF-8 is a good choice.)

Comment: Side note: As far as I know, your `app.set` call (`app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);`) is unnecessary; Express doesn't [document a `port` setting](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.set). But if you want to use the port from the environment, you'll need to change the first argument of `listen` to `process.env.PORT || 3000` (or `process.env.PORT ?? 3000`).

Comment: Which app are you using to write your code?

Comment: SOLVED, thank you guys. I'm usign vs code but when I opened the same file with atom I found a bunch of strange characters instead the js code, unbelievable.
I wrote again the same code and it worked at the first time. Thanks again.